# Blazor .NET 8 - Override RenderMode in child component

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

Like already asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77569241/can-i-set-global-rendermode-interactiveserver-and-override-it-to-use-staticse) i also would like to set the rendermode of child components to "StaticServer" so nothing new in addition to the original question, but i want to explain my needs.

I converted a .NET 6 Blazor application to .NET 8 which seems to work very well if i just set the `@rendermode` for the `Router` and the `HeadOutlet` to `InteractiveServerRenderMode`.

Unfortunately this approach means that i'm not able to use the `static server-side rendering` with `StreamRendering` to use it for forms.

You could ask then: *Why do you use `InteractiveServerRenderMode` then* and the answer is simple: I have to, to keep my funcationalities running which residing in the `Routes.razor` and are based a lot on the life cycle hooks like `OnAfterRender` which are only called if the RenderMode is `InteractiveServerRenderMode`.

So my use case would be to have a `Router` with `InteractiveServerRenderMode` to toggle my loading animations centrally for example and then have "child-components" inside the `RouteView` via the `RouteData`.

Unfortunately i still found no way to do it, so maybe some really smart guy can give the original poster of the question and me a clue how to get this to work.

Comment: Why do you want to "downgrade" a specific component to SSR with `StreanRendering`? You get `StreanRendering` in `InteractiveServerRenderMode`.  Think of it as adding features The prgressing from static to `StreanRendering` to `InteractiveServerRenderMode`.

Comment: `@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false))`